# How to conﬁgure .mocharc.yml to choose exports-style interface?

Tags: mocha.js

How to conﬁgure .mocharc.yml to choose exports-style interface.

It should be like this `___:_____`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write down `ui: 'exports'`